# How to leave the grouped item when a single item in a group is null

Tags: oracle, group-by

How to leave the grouped item when a single item in a group is null.

For Example:

```
Col1    Col2
A        1

A        null

B        3
B        3

C        2
C        null 
C        null

D        2
D        4 
D        9
D        2

So the output :

B
D
```

I trying to exclude the group which has at least one record as null.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answer with the `MINUS` (without the two `DISTINCT`s) because it's clean. However, if you want just a single table access and have a simple looking SQL, then go for `HAVING`:

```
SQL> create table mytable (col1,col2)
  2  as
  3  select 'A', 1 from dual union all
  4  select 'A', null from dual union all
  5  select 'B', 3 from dual union all
  6  select 'B', 3 from dual union all
  7  select 'C', 2 from dual union all
  8  select 'C', null from dual union all
  9  select 'C', null from dual union all
 10  select 'D', 2 from dual union all
 11  select 'D', 4 from dual union all
 12  select 'D', 9 from dual union all
 13  select 'D', 2 from dual
 14  /

Table created.

SQL> select col1
  2    from mytable
  3   group by col1
  4  having count(*) = count(col2)
  5  /

C
-
D
B

2 rows selected.
```

This solution relies on the well known fact that the aggregate function COUNT doesn't count NULL values.

Answer (score 3):

and another:

```
SELECT
      col1
FROM TheTable
MINUS
      SELECT
            col1
      FROM TheTable
      WHERE col2 IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude in advance those values of `Col1` that occur with a `null` for `col2`:

```
select Col1 
from t 
where Col1 not in (select Col1 from t where Col2 is null) 
group by Col1;
```